# how to update combo box with respective textbox in js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dojo

i'm trying to update combobox .if User enter the url on the text box. based on url i am fetching some information and pushing that data into combo box

code:

```
<body>
<div id="updatecmb">
<div class="Urlwithflds"><input type="text" class="Geturl" placeholder="Layer URL" onchange="Getfields()"><button class="rmvbtn">-</button><br><label for="FeaLayerflds">Select Fields</label><select class="Flds" name="FeaLayerflds"></select> </div>
<div class="Urlwithflds"><input type="text" class="Geturl" placeholder="Layer URL" onchange="Getfields()"><button class="rmvbtn">-</button><br><label for="FeaLayerflds">Select Fields</label><select class="Flds" name="FeaLayerflds"></select> </div>
<div class="Urlwithflds"><input type="text" class="Geturl" placeholder="Layer URL" onchange="Getfields()"><button class="rmvbtn">-</button><br><label for="FeaLayerflds">Select Fields</label><select class="Flds" name="FeaLayerflds"></select> </div>
</div>
<script>
function Getfields(events){
   var txturl=events.target.value;
    // i am fetching the details from url and it gives array
    cmbdata=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
    selele=events.currentTarget.children[0].children[4]
    cmbdata.forEach(function(entry) {
    selele.add(new Option(entry));
    }
</script>
<body>
```

my input count increases based on the urls then childs indexing also change how to update if user pasted on second text box only fill second select tag....

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the HTML, pass the function `getFields` with `this` as its argument like so

```
<div id="updatecmb">
  <div class="Urlwithflds">
    <input type="text" class="Geturl" placeholder="Layer URL" onchange="getfields(this)">
    <button class="rmvbtn">-</button>
    <br>
    <label for="FeaLayerflds">Select Fields</label>
    <select class="Flds" name="FeaLayerflds">
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="Urlwithflds">
    <input type="text" class="Geturl" placeholder="Layer URL" onchange="getfields(this)">
    <button class="rmvbtn">-</button>
    <br>
    <label for="FeaLayerflds">Select Fields</label>
    <select class="Flds" name="FeaLayerflds">
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="Urlwithflds">
    <input type="text" class="Geturl" placeholder="Layer URL" onchange="getfields(this)">
    <button class="rmvbtn">-</button>
    <br>
    <label for="FeaLayerflds">Select Fields</label>
    <select class="Flds" name="FeaLayerflds">
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then in the function `getFields` we do

```
function getfields(target){
  const txturl = target.value;
  // assuming we fetched some data from given url as an array
  cmbdata = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];

  // find the element 'select' within the parent element
  selele = target.parentElement.querySelector('select');

  // append each fetched data as new option
  cmbdata.forEach(function(entry) {
    selele.add(new Option(entry));
  });
}
```

Done!

Try it

```js
function getfields(target){
  const txturl = target.value;
  // assuming we fetched some data from given url as an array
  cmbdata = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];

  selele = target.parentElement.querySelector('select');

  cmbdata.forEach(function(entry) {
    selele.add(new Option(entry));
  });
}
```

```css
body {
  background: white;
  color: #323232;

  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;

  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  
  font-family: Helvetica neue, roboto;
}
```

```html
<div id="updatecmb">
  <div class="Urlwithflds">
    <input type="text" class="Geturl" placeholder="Layer URL" onchange="getfields(this)">
    <button class="rmvbtn">-</button>
    <br>
    <label for="FeaLayerflds">Select Fields</label>
    <select class="Flds" name="FeaLayerflds">
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="Urlwithflds">
    <input type="text" class="Geturl" placeholder="Layer URL" onchange="getfields(this)">
    <button class="rmvbtn">-</button>
    <br>
    <label for="FeaLayerflds">Select Fields</label>
    <select class="Flds" name="FeaLayerflds">
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="Urlwithflds">
    <input type="text" class="Geturl" placeholder="Layer URL" onchange="getfields(this)">
    <button class="rmvbtn">-</button>
    <br>
    <label for="FeaLayerflds">Select Fields</label>
    <select class="Flds" name="FeaLayerflds">
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```